# Batch for Mosaic of MODIS Swath

Tags: gdal, modis, batch, mosaic

I'm using gdalwarp to convert a large numbers MODIS Swath (MOD11, MOD06, MOD07) products to TIF and need to mosaic the output images with same day of year.

There is a example of output data:

MOD11_L2.A2014001.1300.006.2016179212636.tif
MOD11_L2.A2014001.1305.006.2016179220648.tif
MOD11_L2.A2014002.1205.006.2016179200050.tif
MOD11_L2.A2014002.1210.006.2016179203811.tif
MOD11_L2.A2014002.1345.006.2016179203914.tif
MOD11_L2.A2014002.1350.006.2016179203951.tif
MOD11_L2.A2014003.1250.006.2016180000700.tif
MOD11_L2.A2014003.1255.006.2016180000720.tif
etc.

The images have 1, 2, 3 or 4 archives. I'm trying to use the following script without sucess:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo '==> Mosaic of MODIS Images'
    g = 001
    for f in *.tif
    do
      echo "==> Processing $f";
      gdalbuildvrt ${f/.tif/.vrt} "*A2014"+$g+"*.tif"
      gdalwarp -overwrite -of GTIFF -tps ${f/.tif/.vrt} Mosaic_${f/.tif/.vrt}.tif
      g = g+1
    done
    echo '==> Script finished with sucess'
    #done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on another post showing how to batch the mosaic process with a python code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    #coding: utf-8
    from osgeo import gdal
    import glob
    for day in range(0, 32):
    day = str('%0.3d' % day)
    gdal.BuildVRT("MOD11_L2.A2014"+day+"_LST.vrt", glob.glob("MOD11_L2.A2014"+day+"*.tif"))
```